# Laravel 500 error when deploying to Elastic Beanstalk (AWS)

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, http-status-code-500

Deployed my website to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, getting 500 server error message
[image]

This only happends when I cache the config. (php artisan config:cache). It works perfectly when I don't cache the config

This is config file when deploying to AWS-

```
option_settings:
-
    namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
    option_name: COMPOSER_HOME
    value: /root

-
    namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini
    option_name: document_root
    value: /public

container_commands:
    01-no_dev:
        command: "composer.phar install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev"
        cwd: "/var/app/staging"
    02-storage_permission:
        command: "chmod -R 755 ./storage"
    03-bootstrap_permission:
        command: "chmod -R 755 ./bootstrap/cache/"
    05-view_cache:
        command: "php artisan view:cache"
    06-config_cache:
        command: "php artisan config:cache"
    07-route_cache:
        command: "php artisan route:cache"
    08-migrate_db:
        command: "php artisan migrate --force"
    09-seed_db:
        command: "php artisan db:seed --force"
    10-npm:
        command: "sudo npm install"
    11-npm_dependencies:
        command: "sudo npm run build"

files:
    /opt/elasticbeanstalk/tasks/taillogs.d/laravel-logs.conf:
        content: /var/app/current/storage/logs/laravel.log
        group: root
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
```

This is my nginx config-

```
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
gzip_static on;
}
```

If ssh into the instance and execute the "php artisan optimize:clear" (clearing the cache), the issues is solved. But I an unable to get it working with caching the config.